# Copiar row de una tabla con jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de copiar un row de una tabla con jquery, esta es la tabla:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Empleado</td>
            <td>Fecha salida</td>
            <td>Fecha regreso</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <select class="selectpicker" name="employee">';
                buildemployees();
    echo '</select>
            </td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="dateI"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="dateO"></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
```

El problema es con el dropdown que esta construido a base de una funcion php buildemployees(), ya eh intentado agregar uno nuevo o copearlo pero no me funciona, este es el codigo jquery que utilizo ahorita:

```
var tbody = $(\'#myTable\').children(\'tbody\');
            var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $(\'#myTable\');
            $(\'.addPlus\').click(function(){
                $("#myTable tbody td").clone().appendTo("#myTable tbody");
            })

            $(\'.addMinus\').click(function(){
                $(\'#myTable\').each(function(){
                    $(\'#myTable\').find(\'tbody tr\').last().remove();
                });
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El hecho de que el dropdown es construido dinamicamente no debe afectar para nada.  Creo que simplemente tienes mal el selector, deberia de ser tr y no td.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var tbody = $('#myTable').children('tbody');
            var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#myTable');
            $('.addPlus').click(function(){
                $("#myTable tbody tr").last().clone().appendTo("#myTable tbody");
            })

            $('.addMinus').click(function(){
                $('#myTable').each(function(){
                    $('#myTable').find('tbody tr').last().remove();
                });
            })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Empleado</td>
            <td>Fecha salida</td>
            <td>Fecha regreso</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <select class="selectpicker" name="employee">';
                <option value="1">Empleado 1</option>
                <option valu ="2">Empleado 2</option>
            </select>
            </td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="dateI"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="dateO"></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
  <button class=addPlus>Clonar</button>
```

Comment: ok al final lo deje asi como el tuyo pero le puse `.last()` para que me copiara el ultimo y no todos, los otros dos input son de tipo fecha y para eso con la clase datepicker llamo al calendario, pero cuando se clonan la libreria del calendario no me funciona, tienes alguna idea de porque?? Saludos

Comment: Despues de clonar, tienes que inicializar los datepickers

Comment: Excelente, muchísimas gracias, sólo me falta editar "data-h". Te cuento, cada celda es identificada gracias a: data-sid, data-cid, data-d, data-h y lo que cambia entre una fila y otra de una misma tabla es el data-h ese es una hora del formato XX:XX ¿cómo puedo sumarle media hora o una hora antes de que se clone la celda?